# Find and fix parentheses split over 2 lines

Tags: regex, vim

I have a large text file with some parenthetical statements split over two lines in a file where every line begins and ends with curly brackets.  So I have one line that ends like

```
(<textA>}\n
```

and the next line begins

```
{<textB>)
```

`<textA>` and `<textB>` will be relatively short and will not have any parentheses, though they could have letters, numbers, or symbols like `-` or `,`.  I need to find these occurrences and replace them with

```
(<textA>),(<textB>)
```

with no newline character.  A regex replacement for `sed`, `bash`, `perl`, or `vim` would be very helpful.

Comment: Lightly tested: `:%s/\m([^)]*\zs}\n{\ze[^(]*)/),(/g`

Comment: @SatoKatsura Thanks for the tip - I didn't know about vim's [`\zs`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/\zs)

Comment: Yeah, I'm over-using `\zs` and `\ze` in my answers, hoping to make more people aware of them.  Very useful features.

Comment: @SatoKatsura - that works perfectly, though I'm not sure how it does it.

Answer (score 2):

In gvim 7.4,

```
:%s/}\n{/),(/
```

works for me in a simple test case.  `}\n{` is the brace pattern you describe, and `:%s` is a global replacement.  This is with `magic` set, which is the default.

To be more selective,

```
:%s/\(([^}]*\)}\n{/\1),(/
```

will check for the `(textA` (not containing a `}`) before the `}\n` and put that text (saved in `\1`) back before the comma upon replace.

Comment: Thanks for the response - for some reason this merges lines that I don't want merged.  It replaces `sulfate(2:1)\"]'}\n{6502276,201,` with `sulfate(2:1)\"]'}{6502276,201,` But the answer-in-comment by Sato Katsura works as I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`, I would use the following command :

```
sed '/^([^)]*{/{N;s/{\n}/),(/}'
```

It tests if a line matches the beginning pattern (a line starting with an open bracket, followed by non-bracket characters and ending with an open curly bracket), an if it's the case append the next line to the pattern buffer then replace `{\n}` with `),(`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below perl script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
my $line = <your_input>;

print "Before regex : ";
print $line;
print "\n";
print "After regex : ";
$line =~ s/\((.*)}\n{(.*)\)/($1),($2)/g;
print $line;
print "\n";
```

I used the regex `\((.*)}\n{(.*)\)`  - the demo of which is [here](https://regex101.com/r/rY9fA8/2)

and the demo of code is [here](https://ideone.com/FNhW2R)